# How to make a curved triangle speech bubble with pseudo-elements?

Tags: css, css-shapes

Hi everyone I am trying to make a curved triangle speech bubble with the CSS `::after` pseudo-element.

I have created like this  **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/qEpqQj)**:

```
.test 
{
position: relative;
width: 430px;
height: 175px;
padding: 0px;
background: #FFFFFF;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
}

.test:after 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 14px 14px 0;
border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
bottom: -14px;
left: 8px;
}
```

How do I do like the picture?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "trapezoid"?...The one in the image is curved...not a trapezoid.

Comment: @TylerH this is good how can i do it like picture ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could use pseudo elements (and their trickery) to generate *something similar* to this:

---

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 350px;
  background: tomato;
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: tomato;
  bottom: 2%;
  left: -15px;
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg);
  transform: rotate(35deg);
}
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  width: 10px;
  background: white;
  bottom: 7%;
  left: -18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg);
  transform: rotate(35deg);
}
```

```html
<div>Hello world</div>
```

---

```css
.test {
  height: 200px;
  width: 350px;
  background: tomato;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
}
.test:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: tomato;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: -6px;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
    border-radius: 0 0 100% 0;
}
.test:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 10px;
  background: white;
  bottom: 24px;
  left: -11px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
.zoom {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 0;
  transform-origin:center center;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin-top:50px;
}
.zoom:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: -25%; top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">hello world</div>

<hr/>

<div class="zoom"></div>
```

---

*tested in Chrome, IE and Firefox (latest versions)*

Comment: As per [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) the 2D transforms will also need a prefixed version. Will work on this and improve anyway for you.

Comment: np glad i could help.

Answer (score 2):

Just another posibility, so that you can choose

```
.test:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border: 0px solid;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: -13px;
    width: 40px;
     height: 40px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 14px 10px 0px 10px white;
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYrJoJ?editors=110)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to achieve that curved triangle shape with pure CSS might be very tricky, so I'd suggest instead you create that shape in vector format, save it off as an SVG and use that in your `:after` element.

Of course save off a PNG fallback for browsers that don't support SVG as well.

As others have already mentioned, a simple CSS potitioning change would get your `:after` element in the bottom left-hand corner, but an SVG might be your only option to get the curved triangle shape.

Answer (score 0):

To move the arrow to the left side, simply change the position of the pseudo element and the borders. At this time, however, I don't think it is possible to create a concave curve without introducing way more complexity, like clipping masks. It would be easier to create a .png image of the curved triangle in Photoshop or Illustrator and then position it next to the speech bubble as desired.

[CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBpoLZ)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-color:#000;
}
.container {
    margin:0px auto;
    width:500px;
    margin-top:50px;
}
.test 
{
    position: relative;
    width: 430px;
    height: 175px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.test:after 
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 0px 15px 16px;
    border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 4px;
    left: -15px;
}
```

Comment: FYI, the question was asking how to get the *very* subtle curved shape, not how to position the after element in the bottom corner.

Comment: @tylerh the triangle is  trapezoid in the picture. I want to make it like that

Comment: @innovation The triangle in the picture is not a trapezoid. It is a sector with an inverted or concave arc.

Comment: @TylerH sorry for my english. You are right i want to make it like that

Comment: @JamieWade Yes, my answer is only partial, but it nearly achieves what he is trying. Most importantly, it puts the triangle in the spot where OP wanted it. The curve is non-trivial and might be added to the answer later if I can achieve it well enough.

Comment: @TylerH i changed my demo can you check it again ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70653/discussion-between-innovation-and-tylerh).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're just positioning it at the bottom instead of the left...

```
.test:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 14px 14px;
    border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 4px;
    left: -14px;
}
```

However this won't replicate the image exactly, which instead shows a curve. While you could probably replicate that curve with nothing but a bunch of clever border tricks, it would make a lot more sense to use an image.