# How to create a curve tail for speech bubble with CSS?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I'm creating a speech bubble with CSS and I have reached this far.

```css
.says{
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background: #BF7EF2;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: -3px 3px 5px #C1B9C8;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.says:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 14px;
  right: -18px;
  height: 20px;
  border-right: 20px solid #BF7EF2;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px 20px;
  transform: translate(0, -4px);
  box-shadow: -3px 3px 5px #C1B9C8;
}

.says:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 7px;
  right: -18px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40px 35px;
  transform: translate(0px, -20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="says">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione aut facere cupiditate, sunt, nisi fugiat consectetur officiis veniam!</div>
```

Basically I have used `:before` and `:after` pseudo class and applied `border-radius`. Then overlapped each other to reach the desire effect. Right now as you can see, I'm using `background: #fff` on `:after` because the current parent's background is white. This will go over many different divs with different bg colors throughout my app. And this is the issue I'm having right now.

*Example-*

[image]

Can I achieve the same "speech-bubble" tail without using the background property on `:after`?
***^ This line explains it's not a duplicate of linked question.***

Or by any other completely different ways?

Comment: @web-tiki The linked question has the answer where he is also using `background` property on `:after` but this is not the case here. I don't want to use background as I stated at the end of my question. It's a different scenario and I think is not a duplicate.

Comment: I see what you mean, the accepted answer doesn't work on serveral background colors but the ones provided by [vals](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28437816/1811992) and [TylerH](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28436966/1811992) do.

Comment: @web-tiki I have achieved the same as vals earlier however the shape here I'm using is different. The sharp edge of the tail is somewhere middle of it's other side. And TylerH's one is not curved, it's an straight triangle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As webtiki says, you can get this result adapting my previous answer (Even though may be it is a little bit difficult)

```css
.container {
  width:300px;
  margin:5px;
}
.test 
{
position: relative;
width: 300px;
height: 150px;
padding: 0px;
background: pink;
border-radius: 6px;
}

.test:after {
    content: '';
    top: 1px;
    right: -29px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 0px solid;
    display: block;
    width: 38px;
     height: 26px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: -21px 9px 0px 8px pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="test"></div>
</div>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYlKY.png" alt="enter image description here">
```

Comment: Thanks! I got the idea now. Just needed to fine-tune some properties to match my expectation. I will edit the answer to my preferred style.

Comment: This is amazing!!